# How do I check /etc/network/interfaces file grammar and test it in C code?

Tags: c

I have a file ("interfaces_new" like /etc/network/interfaces) that I have to test.
Tests concerns File grammar and if I can detect if the settings are correct by testing, it is only better.

I searched and I fell on the ifup command that seems to do everything I want.

The trouble is that I do not want to call system in my C code, so I try to retrieve the sources of ifupdown.

I do not even succeeded, many result indicating to me that a script ifup on most system. On my Debian 7.1.0, it is a EFL binary.

What comes to my questions:
* Is it a usable tool in C code which allows to parse the grammar of a file / etc / network / interfaces?
* Is there a doc listing all the valid options? ifup man gives nothing (or I look bad :/ ), the idea being to make my own parser.
* How to get the source code of the ifup command to Debian 7.1.0?

Comment: Take a look at yacc and bison. Though if you've never done this before writing a parser in C won't be that easy.

Comment: Too broad and multiple questions, so voted to close. But my comment above is giving a few clues.

Answer (score 2):

As I originally commented:

You should read and learn more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). Read [interfaces(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/interfaces.5.html) to understand the format of `/etc/network/interfaces`

The `ifup` command is from [*ifupdown* package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ifupdown), so get its source code.

At last, you simply could [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) the following command

```
 ifup --verbose --no-act --force --all --interfaces=/tmp/interfaces_new
```

assuming your file is in `/tmp/interfaces_new`.

<sup>(Warning, I did not test my suggestion, leaving that to you)</sup>